# Graph SDK Examples

Tags: c#, async-await, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working my way through the '[Use SDks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview)' examples to the 'Create requests' section.  I have the graphClient created but apparently I don't know how to execute the request. It's the most basic of examples directly from the documentation but nothing happens after .GetAsync().

Code Follows:

```
protected async Task MSGraphTest()
    {
        string clientId = "xxxx...";
        string tenantID = "xxxx...";
        string clientSecret = "xxxx...";

        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();
        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

        // Create a new instance of GraphServiceClient with the authentication provider.
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

        Microsoft.Graph.User user = await graphClient.Me
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
        Results_TxtBx.Text += "User Info: " + user.DisplayName;
    }
```

Comment: Did you Grant Consent to the MS Graph API in the Azure AD App Registration?

Comment: It may help to surround the code with a try..catch to see if any exceptions are happening

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Graph has User.Read.All Application Permissions Admin consent granted.

Comment: The try-catch block yielded the same results.  No errors, no response just the execution of the code stops.  It appears like it's in the "await" phase of the async operation and nothing ever returns to it.

I think there's something wrong in the way I'm calling the method but I have no idea.

Comment: Since the permissions are registered with the app in Azure AD could the fact that I'm debugging in visual studio with a localhost be a permissions problem?

Comment: what happens if you try the same Graph API call in Microsoft Graph explorer? Does it returns the values for the me or not?

Comment: Following up on this: I abandoned this approach using the SDK and posted the queries directly.